# Can't delete items from Mongo Database in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js, meteorite

I have created an object in Meteorjs to hold the database info for N numbers of dice rolls, and then the dice are displayed using handlebars #each iterator. Here is some of my code:

The global Mongo collection:

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection('items');</code>
```

When I roll the dice, this is what happens to the collection when a button is clicked:

```
    //Don't want to bore you with all code, so here's just important parts...
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * numSides) +1);
    var numDice = 6;// It's really a variable passed in, but for here it's 6. 
    for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
              Items.insert(item: randomNumber)
    };
```

And then they display the info as dice because it displays numbers that I have CSS'd to look like Dice. But I'm straying here... Anyway, the dice rolling is awesome, but I want to clear the dice when I roll again. right now, they just keep adding up. And when I try to use any method to delete Mongo DB Items stuff, it crashes my app. Since I'm not sure how to debug very well yet in a browser, I need some help, and I'mm going to ask it here...

Now, my main problem is, when the dice are rolled again, I want to purge the database and start again. I am new to JavaScript and Meteor, and come from Java && Ruby land, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I've tried

```
Items.removeIndexes(), 
Items.purge(), 
Items.remove({})
```

They all just freeze my app, and the numbers I displayed in the #each iterator are still there. I thought it would delete the stuff, and push the changes... No??? Please help.

The code is on GitHub @ http://www.github.com/rabbitfighter81/DMware/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [remove](http://docs.meteor.com/#remove) method, but if you call it from the client, you can only remove one document per call, and the selector must refer to the documents `_id` field. So, here's an example to remove all the documents in a collection the client has:

```js
TheCollection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    TheCollection.remove(doc._id)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. JS community is very nice so far. No noobcakes calling or anything. I'm used to be people being rude, so thank you, I will try to fumble with it and let you know if it works... Also, I'm aware of the Meteor docs, handlebar docs, but are there any other good resources that you would recommend to get a better grip on these kinds of things cause I'd rather read than ask questions, however, most Meteor books out now are outdated (i.e. circa 2012 using router, instead of iron-router, etc... a lot is different, and the books I've found, things don't work anymore).

Comment: @JoshuaMichael, I would recommend reading through the docs; that will give you a hint of what you can do in Meteor. But also check [the learn page on meteors website](https://www.meteor.com/learn-meteor), especially Discover Meteor and EventedMind.

Comment: Once again, thank you. Peppe L-G.  Your solution worked like a charm :)